# VB.NET - Check if URL is a directory or file

Tags: vb.net, directory

Is there a way, in VB.NET, to check if a URL is a directory? I've seen a lot of methods of checking if a local path is a directory but what about a remote url (i.e. http://website.com/foo) I read that some plain text files have no extension so I need a solution other than checking what if the file name contains a space or something.

Comment: what if `foo` is just data ?

Comment: @Guy I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Check this solution, it sould be same as C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116985/c-sharp-check-if-a-given-url-is-file-or-directory

Comment: @Guy I can't create an array of file extensions because my program displays files in the directory so any extension may be used

Comment: Have you tried to use `File.Exists(url)` and `Directory.Exists(url)` ?

Comment: @Guy `it will return false for http/ftp cases`

Comment: Look at this page url, it ends with `vb-net-check-if-url-is-a-directory-or-file` , but it's not a File or Directoery. So It really depends on what you need to do with this information.

Comment: It's not a directory??

Comment: I don't think that `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858953/vb-net-check-if-url-is-a-directory-or-file` is a dir, it used by the server as a string and not as a file or dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) class:

```
'get the file attributes for file or directory
FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes("c:\\Temp")

'detect whether its a directory or file
If ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Its a directory")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Its a file")
End IF
```

Or you can use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class:

```
Private IsLocalPath(Byval p As String) As Boolean
  Return New Uri(p).IsFile
End Function
```

You can enhance this method to include support for certain invalid URIs:

```
Private IsLocalPath(Byval p As String) As Boolean
  If (p.StartsWith("http:\\")) Then      
    Return False
  End IF

  Return New Uri(p).IsFile
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to try to download the file from the Internet, if the download succeeded So it is a file, otherwise it is not a file (but you don't know for sure that this is a directory).

Comment: Dang. Is that really the only way?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
If System.IO.Path.HasExtension(FileAddress.Text)  Then
   MessageBox.Show("Its a file")
Else
   MessageBox.Show("Its a directory")
End IF
```